# How to generate random number with no repeat above limit?

Tags: random, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I think I've hit the upper limit level for random generating numbers.

Is there any workaround for this?

I need to generate ten unique, 19-digit, random numbers in one formula/string.

I have this: `=TRUNC (RAND() * (9999999999999999999 - 1) + 1)` but spreadsheet rewrites it to:

```
=TRUNC (RAND() * (9999999999999990000 - 1) + 1)
```

so I guess the limit is 9999999999999990000.

Desired output format in A1:

```
2459759093970314589,6393667943286134368,4897561254458152397, etc.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numeric precision in Excel is ~15 significant digits. An alternative would be to generate the random numbers as strings (the fist character needs to be in the range of 1 to 9, the others from the range of 0-9). Something like this:

```
=CONCAT(
TRUNC(RAND()*9+1);
TRUNC(RAND()*10);
TRUNC(RAND()*10);
TRUNC(RAND()*10);
...
)
```

Comment: Hm. Just tried it and it works for me. Try converting to text before concatenating: `=CONCAT(TEXT(TRUNC(RAND()*9+1);"0");TEXT(TRUNC(RAND()*10);"0");...)`

Comment: and you getting 19 digit number out of this string? coz I'm getting only 2 digits and with more TRUNCs then 2 it always results in **#N/A**

Comment: This works for me: `=CONCAT(TRUNC(RAND()*9+1);TRUNC(RAND()*10);TRUNC(RAND()*10);TRUNC(RAND()*10);TRUNC(RAND()*10);TRUNC(RAND()*10);TRUNC(RAND()*10);TRUNC(RAND()*10);TRUNC(RAND()*10);TRUNC(RAND()*10);TRUNC(RAND()*10);TRUNC(RAND()*10);TRUNC(RAND()*10);TRUNC(RAND()*10);TRUNC(RAND()*10);TRUNC(RAND()*10);TRUNC(RAND()*10);TRUNC(RAND()*10);TRUNC(RAND()*10);TRUNC(RAND()*10);TRUNC(RAND()*10);TRUNC(RAND()*10);TRUNC(RAND()*10);TRUNC(RAND()*10);TRUNC(RAND()*10);TRUNC(RAND()*10);TRUNC(RAND()*10);TRUNC(RAND()*10);TRUNC(RAND()*10);TRUNC(RAND()*10);TRUNC(RAND()*10);TRUNC(RAND()*10);TRUNC(RAND()*10))`

Comment: In Excel, that is. Looks like your `CONCAT` only accepts 2 parameters?

Comment: Try `=CONCAT(TRUNC(RAND()*9+1);CONCAT(TRUNC(RAND()*10);TRUNC(RAND()*10)))`

Comment: works, thank you: **=CONCAT(TRUNC(RAND()*9+1);CONCAT(TRUNC(RAND()*9+1);CONCAT(TRUNC(RAND()*9+1);CONCAT(TRUNC(RAND()*9+1);CONCAT(TRUNC(RAND()*9+1);CONCAT(TRUNC(RAND()*9+1);CONCAT(TRUNC(RAND()*9+1);CONCAT(TRUNC(RAND()*9+1);CONCAT(TRUNC(RAND()*9+1);CONCAT(TRUNC(RAND()*9+1);CONCAT(TRUNC(RAND()*9+1);CONCAT(TRUNC(RAND()*9+1);CONCAT(TRUNC(RAND()*9+1);CONCAT(TRUNC(RAND()*9+1);CONCAT(TRUNC(RAND()*9+1);CONCAT(TRUNC(RAND()*9+1);CONCAT(TRUNC(RAND()*9+1);CONCAT(TRUNC(RAND()*10);TRUNC(RAND()*10)))))))))))))))))))**

Comment: is there a 100% bullet proof chance, that it wont generate same 10 numbers? or I should keep in mind that its only 99% solution? pls see EDIT2

Comment: No, that's the randomness of it - there is a chance, albeit small, it will be all the same digits. For 19 digits, the chance is approx 10^-18. If you generate a million numbers per second, it will happen in average once in 30 thousand years :)

Answer (score 1):

[google-spreadsheets](/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheets)

[image]

`=TRANSPOSE(regexextract(JOIN("",ArrayFormula(RANDBETWEEN(row(INDIRECT("a1:a"&A1*A2))^0-1,9))),rept("(\d{"&A1&"})",A2)))`